# how do you update the cache after a mutation that returns a circular type?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

All of the answers I have found relate to graphql. I need to know how to update the cache on the client using apollographql.

Given this Friend type and mutation.

```
type Friend {
  id: String
  name: String
  friends: [Friend]
}

type Mutation {
  createFriend (
    friends: [FriendInput]
  ): [Friend]
}
```

The friends array is circular. How do you represent this in the response and how do you update the clients cache?

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in the friends of a specific person, your store probably contains a bunch of `Friend` objects (I would actually call them `Person`, and `friends` is just a field on the `Person` type). For doing the mutation, it should be enough to provide the `id` of each friend of that new person, unless you want to create not just one person at a time in these mutations, but multiple.

For the mutation response, just include the data that you need for each friend. If you need the `name` and `id` of each of the persons `friends`, then include that as well. Most likely you won't need to go two levels deep, but if you want to, you can do that as well.

In Apollo Client, you don't actually need to do anything special to have this data be properly written into your store, because Apollo Client automatically normalizes by the `id` field and stores each friend only once. So if you're sure that you already have all the persons on the client, it will be enough to ask only for the `id` of each friend, so for example:

```
{
  createFriend( friends: [{ name: 'Joe', friends: [{ id: 1}, {id: 4}] }]) {
    id
    name
    friends {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```